# Should I remove my old question that was unclear and closed?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I have looked at the other meta questions (if you know of one that is a duplicate this I will delete this), but none are good for my situation.

I have [an old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36212228/how-do-i-compiler-a-c-file-from-the-command-line-in-visual-studio) that is super bad. Now should I leave it or delete it?

Now that the questions is gone I went and got it from the deletion here it is:

I have visual studio code and I am learning C. I have run into a problem when trying to compile as VS Code does not have a compiler. How do I compile a C file from the command line in visual studio?

Comment: This point is moot now... it was deleted by 10kers

Comment: Now I'm curious to learn what was that question that was considered so bad.

Comment: @VictorJalencas i put it in the question now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think ahead, you question may be bad now, but

1. You can always come back to it later and edit it
2. Someone still may find it useful
3. People here actually take the time to update/edit questions and answers they wrote years ago!

Stackoverflow is a Q&A site, which imply that you're not only asking someone to help you right now, but rather create a possible reference or a solution for someone else in the future.

Don't delete you question, try to fix it instead. Maybe it will get upvoted a couple of times after.

If it's REALLY bad, it will get deleted (eventually) by people on the review queues.

Comment: _If it's REALLY bad, it will get deleted (eventually) by people on the review queues_ -  Good point. I probably should have mentioned that as well in my answer.

Comment: I think fixing isn't possible in this question without radically changing the question, which is something most users don't feel comfortable with (I for one, don't care as long as it gets *really fixed*).

Comment: "without radically changing the question", it should be find as long as the subject and scope remain the same, right?